# how to vertical align bottom inline block elements in container

Tags: css

I have the following html structure

```
<div class="examples">
   <div class="option"></div>
   <div class="option"></div>
   <div class="option"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.examples {
    whitespace: nowrap;
    min-height: 400px;
}
.option {
    width: 18%;
    max-width: 18%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How can I vertically align inline blocks (option) at the bottom of the container (examples) using CSS? These are a row of images inside the examples container. I tried vertical align: bottom, but that doesn't work and I want to stay away from flex because of lack of cross browser support. I also want to stay away from absolute position because the elements (option) are a row of images.

Comment: Withhout flexbox or absolute positioning...you can't. However I'm a little unclear on what it is you are trying to do. Why do these "rows of images" need to be at the bottom of the div? What is above them?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and use `display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;` on the container div.  That should put them at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.examples {
    whitespace: nowrap;
    min-height: 400px;

  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

.aligner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.option {
    width: 18%;
    max-width: 18%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="examples">
  <div class="aligner">
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
    <div class="option"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```